# Create circular pulse for MKOverlay (similar to the Current Location overlay)

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I have a question regarding the mapview of an IOS app. I have mapview that shows a standard overlay surrounding one specific coordinate, and I also have the normal current location marker that shows up in Google Maps. When you look at the standard current location in google maps, it shows the current location plus a circular overlay with a pulsating circle. I'm trying to create that same type of pulsating circle overlay for the other location marker on my mapview.

Here is the code for my standard map overlay. Does anyone know how to imitate the look of the current location but for a specific marked location? Sorry for the muddled language, just trying to explain it as best as I can.

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{
    MKCircleView* aView = [[[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:(MKCircle *)overlay] autorelease];

    aView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.35];
    aView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
    aView.lineWidth = 3;

    return aView;

}
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen an example on github, but can't remember the name of it.

The idea was that MKCircle can't be used for that purpose.

The trick was in use of UIImage with drawed circle and constant scale animation applied to that image...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

http://yickhong-ios.blogspot.it/2012/04/animated-circle-on-mkmapview.html

it's a library doing exactly what you need